# Rails destroy does not happening

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, oop

I have tried multiple variations of the code below but it does not work. Basically when I destroy a Thread post in my forum - it does delete all the replies that belongs to him with dependent = > destroy

Each user has many read_post_ids which basically records the id of every reply that he has read in read_post_id.read_id.

The code below is from the destroy function in replies controller. What I want is before the destruction of the reply to go trough each user and delete that read_post record

```
User.all.each(:readonly => false) do |user|
  user.read_post_ids.all.each(:readonly => false) do |read_post|
    if read_post.read_id == @reply.id
      read_post.destroy
      user.save
      user.read_post_ids.save
    end
  end
end
```

I don't have any errors. The reply is deleted successfully. Only the read_post remains undeleted.

Comment: Is it `read_post_ids ` or `read_posts`, are they associated?

Comment: @SebastianPalma read_post_ids is table and read_posts is a column in that table

Comment: did you use `dependent :destroy` at model side?

Comment: @Gabbar no because it will help only if I destroy the user, but I am not destroying the user, I am destroying the reply.

Comment: what are you trying to destroy? an instance of `read_post_ids`?

Comment: @Cyzanfar an instance of user.read_post_ids

Comment: Do you know that `read_post.read_id == @reply.id` return true in some case?

Comment: it has to return true since the ID's are matching in the server console otuput @Cyzanfar

Comment: I recommend to you use debugger, and go step by step in this method. You can use pry gem (and binding.pry as stop point), or if you using RubyMine - it includes awesome debugger. This issue just need to be debugged. And you will realize where the problem.

Comment: yes as @OleksiiBaidan mentioned put a `binding.pry` right before the line `read_post.destroy` and test from there